# How could Sherlock find the kids in the Reichenbach Fall using the foot prints?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

He analyzed the traces that were left by the kids shoes and used them to realize which places the kids went to *later*. How could that work?

Answer (score 7):

Sherlock wasn’t analysing the kids’ footprints, but the kidnappers’. From the scene where the footprints are analysed at the lab:

> Sherlock opens container with footprint scratched from the school’s floor and uses tweezers to grab a piece. *“Oil, John. The oil in **the kidnapper’s footprint.** It’ll lead us to Moriarty.”* Drops piece into test tube with some chemical.
>
> Sherlock obtains a sample from the test tube with a pipette. *“All the chemical traces on his shoe have been preserved. The sole of the shoe is like a passport. If we’re lucky, we can see everything he’s been up to.“*  Begins to look at sample under microscope.

It is entirely plausible that the kidnappers had already been at their hideout before performing the kidnapping.

Comment: Good answer, but please provide source of the citation.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong: Ehm, it’s directly transcribed from the audio/screen.

Comment: I see. Fair enough.